# Convert datetime to UTC

Tags: python, timezone

I have a date string like - 2015-01-05T10:30:47-0800,

It looks to me that this is some timezone because of the offset. How can I get a date string which is in the UTC timezone from the above date string.

I tried the following -

```
datestring = '2015-01-05T10:30:47-0800'
from dateutil import parser
d = parser.parse(datestring) # datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 10, 30, 47, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -28800))
import pytz
d.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC')) # datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 18, 30, 47, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

EDIT -
The above code returns the correct answer. My bad!

Comment: tried anything yet? https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser

>>> d = dateutil.parser.parse('2015-01-05T10:30:47-0800')
>>> d.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzutc())
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 18, 30, 47, tzinfo=tzutc())
```